# Acumatica, how do I execute an export scenario and get the output file

Tags: export, acumatica

How can I do it?
Some code (NOT working, but does seem to execute the needed scenario):

```
SYExportProcessSingle g = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SYExportProcessSingle>();
SYMapping m = new PXSelect<SYMapping, Where<SYMapping.name, Equal<Required<SYMapping.name>>>>(g).SelectSingle(scenarioName);
if (m != null)
{
    g.MappingsSingle.Current = g.MappingsSingle.Search<SYMappingActive.name>(scenarioName);
    g.Prepare.Press();
    PXLongOperation.WaitCompletion(g.UID);
    g.Export.Press();
    g.MappingsSingle.Current = g.MappingsSingle.Search<SYMappingActive.name>(scenarioName);
    g.GetLatestFile.Press();
    // g.GetLatestFile.Press(adapter);
    PXLongOperation.WaitCompletion(g.UID);
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide some details on why you want to do this and what you want to achieve? You can simply schedule the export scenario to run at some interval.

Comment: Have a variety (e.g. 9+) of different reports needed daily.  Each must generate a CSV file (different data in each), and then FTPed to a remote machine.  I don't want to hard code the data feeds, since the export scenario handles this nicely.  So trying to execute the 9, getting a data file for each, add a header to the file, and then transmit through sFTP.

Comment: Oh yes, it's for a subset of the SiteID in the system, each can belong to 0..1 "exports", likely to be at least 3-4 different "Exports", each covering a subset of sites